# Optimal way to create a session and login a user with unique id via codeigniter

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, session

I have been rebuilding my social network in code igniter and am looking for an optimal way to start a session as logged in when the user logs in ( maybe contrary to using code igniters session class? as I want to use their id that is created when they make their account)

I have been able to CREATE a user and hash and salt their password and log them in using the hashed password.

My site is going to have a lot of 'logged in' and 'logged out' views that vary due to if the user is signed in or not.

That being said, upon login I want to start a logged in session with the id that is created upon sign-up.

Here is my controller that logs the user in minus what I'm trying to do.

```
function validate_credentials()
{
    $this->load->model('user_model', 'um');
    $login = $this->input->post('submit');
        $this->load->library('encrypt');

    if($login) {
        $user = $this->um->
                    validate(array('email' => $this->input->post('email')));
        if( $user ) {
            if($user->password == $this->encrypt->sha1( $user->salt .
                         $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password')))) {
                  $this->session->set_userdata( array('email' => 
                                   $this->input->post('email')
                  ));
                  redirect('account/dashboard');
                  exit;
            }
        }
    }
    $this->index();
}

/*---------- EDIT ----------*/
Getting these errors:



  Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mycomputer/Sites/cl_ci_new/application/controllers/auth.php:44)

    Filename: libraries/Session.php

    Line Number: 672

    Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mycomputer/Sites/cl_ci_new/application/controllers/auth.php:44)

    Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

    Line Number: 542

and here are those lines in my code or the Session.php file:

    // Set the cookie
        setcookie(
            this->sess_cookie_name,
            $cookie_data,
            $expire,
            $this->cookie_path,
            $this->cookie_domain,
            $this->cookie_secure
                );
```

and the url_helpers.php:

```
switch($method)
        {
            case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
                break;
            default         : header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
                break;
        }
```

I'm not understanding what the problem is....

Comment: what is the BEST way to start a session using the user's id? i.e.:$user->id and mark them as logged in?

Comment: I've been able to create the session id and it's a random string:$this->load->library('session');
      $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
      echo $this->session->userdata('session_id');

Comment: yields this:821f6d2c05fbf81b8c9f81077d28fe38

Comment: or once I start the session can I do something like if($user->id == logged_in){ do stuff }?

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to auto load the url helper and the errors are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On successful validation save a variable in session:

```
if ($user->password == ...) {
     $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
}
else {
     $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', FALSE);
}
```

Later on, when needed, check:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {

}
```

Comment: should I not do:if ($user->password == ...) {
     $user = $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
}
else {
     $user = $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', FALSE);
}
or is that redundant?

Comment: If needed you should hold a variable `$logged_in` and in the `$user` variable keep the user's object with all its data.

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. your saying $logged_in = $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in');? I guess I'm wondering how to show that the user is logged in, in a variable

Comment: If you need it in a variable, you can always do `$logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in')`

Comment: What is $user? Is it a class you created?

Comment: CONTROLLER:public function dashboard() {
 
  $data['main_content'] = 'account/dashboard';
  $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
  $this->load->library('session');
  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $this->user_varification();
  $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  if($logged_in)
  {
   echo $user->id;
  }else{
   echo "not logged in";
  }
 }
MODEL:function user_varification() 
 {
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users order by id desc LIMIT 1');
  foreach ($query->result() as $user);
 }

Comment: In that case, yes. You can create a class variable called `logged_in` and set it on default to `false`.